# Elm call external Javascript on load

Tags: javascript, materialize, elm

I'm trying to add *Materializecss* dropdown to an *Elm* app.

I would like to call the `$(".dropdown-trigger").dropdown();` to activate the dropdown. 
But if I call this function in *JQuery* onload it seems *Elm* have not already make the `ul` list needed to have dropdown elements.

How can I make it work in a simple way without bringing anothers libs ?

Comment: I followed this guide, which explain how make it work https://www.gizra.com/content/elm-port-alternatives/

Comment: If you go to the Official Elm Guide and look at JS interop (https://guide.elm-lang.org/interop/) you'll see you have 3 options. In the case of a component, you have 1 official option: "custom elements". If you want to reuse js component libraries, I'd look into custom elements. It will be the best choice in the long run.